# VS2012, C#, Monogame - load asset exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, monogame

I've been fighting with this problems for days now, browsing through the net, yet nothing helped me solve it: I'm creating a MonoGame application on Visual Studio 2012, yet when trying to load a texture I get the following problem:

> Could not load Menu/btnPlay asset!

I have set content directory: Content.RootDirectory = "Assets"; Also the file btnPlay.png has properties set: Build Action: Content and Copy to Output directory: Copy if newer.

My constructor and LoadContent functions are totally empty, but have a look yourself:

```
public WizardGame()
{
    Window.Title = "Just another Wizard game";

    _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

    Content.RootDirectory = "Assets";
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Menu/btnPlay");

    _graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    _graphics.ApplyChanges();
}
```

I would be glad for any help! I'm totally desperate about the problem....

Answer (score 6):

Under VS2012, Windows 8 64-bits and latest MonoGame as of today (3.0.1) :

- create a subfolder named *Assets*
- set *Copy to Output* to anything else than *Do not copy*
- prepend *assets* to your texture path when loading it

[image]

```
namespace GameName2
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private Texture2D _texture2D;
        private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            _texture2D = Content.Load<Texture2D>("assets/snap0009");
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(_texture2D, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's your texture drawn :D

[image]

**Note:**

By convenience I kept the original value that the content's root directory points to : `Content`.

However, you can also directly specify `Assets` in the path:

```
Content.RootDirectory = @"Content\Assets";
```

Then load your texture without prepending `Assets` to its path:

```
_texture2D = Content.Load<Texture2D>("snap0009");
```

Comment: Good post and nice visuals. Only I'm lacking the bit where you explain that he needs to set the Content.RootDirectory = "Assets"; back to "Content". The visuals explain your map structure but maybe it's also nice to write that small part down in 2 sentences about the Content map.

Comment: Actually I've never said to specify the root directory :) Why I think this is better ? Because these are the settings out-of-the-box.

Comment: I know you haven't but the question describes he had changed this to Assets and it could create in some scenarios confusion that's the reason why I commented to rule out those scenario's and making your answer even better.